# Error 'Request not handled correctly' when sending file over Bluetooth via Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, windows, xamarin, bluetooth

I'm writing an Android app on Xamarin to send an XML file over Bluetooth to my Windows laptop. Here's my code

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        var xmlAsset = Assets.Open("FileXML.xml");
        var SendFile = new Java.IO.File(xmlAsset.ToString());
        var sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionSend);
        sendIntent.SetType(".xml ->text/xml");
        sendIntent.SetComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.bluetooth", "com.android.bluetooth.opp.BluetoothOppLauncherActivity"));
        sendIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(SendFile));
        StartActivity(sendIntent);
    }
}
```

No errors show up in the code during build, and it deploys correctly. It gets as far as the menu to select a Bluetooth device to send it to, but when I make a selection, the sending fails, and I get a notification saying 'Request can't be handled correctly'. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you trying to send from your Android device to a *Windows*-based PC?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do

Comment: Common issue on Windows, make sure all your drivers are updated, also your mime type should be `text/xml` or `Application/xml` depending upon the xml content.

Comment: I did what you suggested, but I'm still getting the same error. Digging a bit deeper, I saw that in my Bluetooth transfer history, it's listed as 'Unknown File'. Is it because the app cannot get hold of the XML file for some reason?